# ImageProcessor images lose quality

Tags: iis, imageprocessor

I've some problem about the quality.
The quality of the resized picture is not the best, I tryied before with an image jpeg
http://mb-website.com/prova.html
and then with one .jpg took from my iphone X.
http://mb-website.com/prova2.html

ImageProcessor (2.8.0), ImageProcessor.Web (4.11.0), ImageProcessor.Web.Config (2.6.0), I dont use visual or whatever program, everything done by myself.

The cache.config, processing.config and security.config are not modified.
I put them in root/config/imageprocessor

Could I add something to get a better result?
Thank you

Comment: did you enable the compression in iis?[link1](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/issues/483), [link2](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/issues/343)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I dont undestand what you mean, can you explain me please?

Comment: Do you host the site on iis server?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal yes

Comment: @JalpaPanchal for example here as well, in my website, the pictures in Last Works section are resized and they dont have a high quality, it's not a professional result http://mb-website.com/website/completed/4/index.aspx?activity=barber